# CSS root to host

Tags: css, shadow-dom

I'm working on an existing app.

In this app, all css variables are declared in a file `variables.css` under the pseudo-class `:root` like this :

```
:root {
    --nui-color-primary: #1979ff;
}
```

And, for a particular component (a popover), we are variables declared like this in an other file `popover.scss` :

```
:host {
   --popover-content-color: var(--nui-color-primary); 
}

.popover-inner-content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  padding: unit(1.5) unit(0.5) unit(1.5) unit(1.5);
  color: var(--popover-content-color);
}
```

But the `:host` doesn't seems to have access to the `:root` variables, because the color isn't the good one for my example (black instead of blue).

I am not very familiar with the Shadow DOM and I'm new on this project so I take back what was done before.

Any idea of how I can call root variables on the host ?

Comment: `variables.css` should be loaded before `popover.scss`. Check the order in which the files load.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem about CSS `:root` variables with Shadow DOM, but my project is to parse a HTML file and put the result to a Shadow DOM element.

My solution is just copy the variables inside `:root` to a new `<style>` element with `:host {}` and put the `<style>` element to the `<body>` element inside the same DOM object.

Take your example to modify:

```
<body>
<style>
:host {
    --nui-color-primary: #1979ff;
}
</style>
...
</body>
```